# Automated checking of non-dealloc'd properties in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, properties, automated-tests

Is there an automated way to check for properties defined in a class that are not deallocated in the `dealloc` method that can be built into unit tests? I am hoping to help automate memory management testing, as that seems to be my biggest fault when coding in Objective-C for the iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've tried this or not but there is a 'build and Analyze' option in the Build menu that does a pretty good job of this.  I use @property's everywhere and it seemed to pick all of mine up correctly.

I encountered this option by an accidental click and found it to be so valuable!

Comment: Although not as automated as I would like, I think this will suffice. Thanks for the tip.